# Add item to Owl Carousel in the first postion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

So far have it working where I can dynamically add a slide into an owl carousel. But I'm not sure how to get it to be placed at the beginning? I've combed through the docs a bit, and it's not really clear to me how to get to be the first slide, rather than the last.

Here's what I have so far:

**JS**

```
  var img = '<div class="item"><img src="../images/added-img.jpg"></div>';
    $("#carousel").data('owlCarousel').addItem(img);
```

I would think that this would be pretty easy, but I'm not sure what the method is to get it to be in the first position.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just figured it out.

Needs to be this:

**JS**

```
  var img = '<div class="item"><img src="../images/added-img.jpg"></div>';
  $("#carousel").data('owlCarousel').addItem(img,[0]);
```

I dug through it a bit more and realized that `addItem` will add a slide on a given position. So by passing a value to it, would insert the slide at a specific position in the carousel. One other issue I had was I was using `[1]` when testing, which was inserting the slide in the second position. By setting it to `[0]` makes inserts the slide at the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

@ultraloveninja 
There may be some weird things after added.
I use below:

```
var img = '<div class="item"><img src="../images/added-img.jpg"></div>';
$("#carousel").data('owlCarousel').trigger('add.owl.carousel', [$(img), 0])
        .trigger('refresh.owl.carousel')
        .trigger('to.owl.carousel', [0, 500]);
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {
var owl = $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
loop: true,
margin: 10,
responsiveClass: true,
autoplay: true,
responsive: {
0: {
items: 1,
nav: true
},
600: {
items: 3,
nav: false
},
1000: {
items: 5,
nav: true,
loop: false
}
},
attachable: function () {

```
            },
            triggerable: function (data) {
                this.data = data + 'jfeoajfeo'
                console.log('replace')
                console.log(data)
            }

        });

        var img = '<div class="item"><img src="../images/added-img.jpg"></div>';
        owl.trigger('add.owl.carousel', img)


    });
```

Comment: Please format your code because it is very hard to read it in this form. It is also recommended to describe your answer alongside the code so the OP can figure it out how you achieved the result